# How can I check for an InternalsVisibleTo attribute on an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, castle, ilmerge

I've used ILMerge to merge a secondary assembly that is itself merged with Castle.DynamicProxy, having set most if not all of the normally-public Castle types to internal. When I use the code from the secondary assembly that is dependent on the Castle types, I get a TypeLoadException saying that access is denied.

The first step to check is that my merged assembly has the InternalsVisibleTo attribute still set for the DynamicProxy2 assembly. Any way to check this?

Comment: Automatically? You can check yourself by using either DotPeek or Ildasm, but thats manually.

Comment: Manually or in code is fine. I've opened an assembly I know has the attribute set in dotPeek 1.3, but I haven't been able to locate any mention of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) shows this by double-clicking the assembly. `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` should be visible zero or more times.

Also, [Ildasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be able to tell you this by double-clicking the `MANIFEST` of the assembly. A yellow popup shows lines that start with `.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can load the assembly itself, you can use `Assembly.GetCustomAttributes`:

```
var asm = ...;
var internals = asm.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InternalsVisibleToAttribute),
                                        false);
var foundDynamicProxy2 = internals.Cast<InternalsVisibleToAttribute>()
                                  .Any(x => x.AssemblyName == "DynamicProxy2");
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to load the assembly in code and use reflection on it.