# Creating a Sitecore Database with NSubstitute allowed despite internal constructor

Tags: sitecore, nsubstitute

I discovered an odd anomaly with NSubstitute class instantiation.  Working with Sitecore 8.1 update 3 Sitecore.Kernell.dll, the following test passes:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanCreateSubstituteDatabase()
{
  Database db = Substitute.For<Sitecore.Data.Database>("sub");
  db.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

This despite the fact that there is only an internal constructor for Sitecore.Data.Database:

```cs
 internal Database(string name)
 {....
```

I have confirmed that this is not normal behavior for NSubstitute. I created a project "ExternalLibrary" with this code:

```cs
namespace ExternalLibrary
{
    public class Foo
    {
        internal Foo(string bar)
        {
            Bar = bar;
        }

        public string Bar { get; }
    }
}
```

When I try to use NSubstitute to instantiate this in a separate library,

```cs
namespace NSubClassInstantiation
{
    using ExternalLibrary;
    using FluentAssertions;
    using NSubstitute;
    using Xunit;

    public class FooTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void CanInstantiate()
        {
            var foo = Substitute.For<Foo>("baz");

            foo.Bar.Should().Be("baz");
        }
    }
}
```

the test fails as expected with the following exception,

```cs
System.NotSupportedException: Parent does not have a default constructor. The default constructor must be explicitly defined.
```

Why is this error not thrown with the Sitecore.Data.Database class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSubstitute namespace is marked InternalsVisibleTo in Sitecore.Kernel.

[What is the DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405040/what-is-the-dynamicproxygenassembly2-assembly)

From Sitecore.Kernel: [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]

Comment: Bam, that was quick. :D

Comment: Haha. Only because I'd been studying Sitecore.Kernel attributes closely, quite recently ;-)

Comment: Of course, this means an Evil Implementer can do an end-run around the constructor, and use SubstituteForPartsOf to make their own DBs. ;)

Comment: I've named Test projects "Sitecore.IntegrationTests" in the past ;-)  As for evil - how about: https://github.com/cassidydotdk/Sitecore.Datalift/blob/master/src/Sitecore.Datalift.Tests/SitecoreFaker.cs

Comment: Double clicking on the assembly in DotPeek or ReSharper AssemblyExplorer shows the Assembly properties, including the line Mark included above.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700047/how-can-i-check-for-an-internalsvisibleto-attribute-on-an-assembly